# KO computed array filter not working

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, foreach

I've been learning KO but only know have I really took my time to create a small project with it from scratch.

I'm having trouble comprehending my issue, I'll briefly explain the logic:

You have pages, and those pages can have pages (children).

```
/* Defines a Page */
var page = function(ID, alias, body, connections) {
this.ID = ko.observable(ID);
this.alias = ko.observable(alias);
this.body = ko.observable(body);
this.connections = ko.observableArray(connections);
};

var dummyPages = [
new page(1, 'Alias #1', 'Body #1', [5]),
new page(2, 'Alias #2', 'Body #2', []),
new page(3, 'Alias #3', 'Body #3', [2,3]),
new page(4, 'Alias #4', 'Body #4', [5]),
new page(5, 'Alias #5', 'Body #5', [6]),
new page(6, 'Alias #6', 'Body #6', [7]),
new page(7, 'Alias #7', 'Body #7', [1, 4])
];
```

What I'm trying to do here is use a computed function what will be placed on a foreach html element.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: foreachConnectionAliases" style="text-align: left">
```

What it will do is basically get the children info of a page.

Here's my code:

```
/* Return the pages that are connected to the clicked one */
this.foreachConnectionAliases = ko.computed(function(){
alert(this.chPages);
if(typeof this.chPages === "undefined")
  return null;

var filtered =  ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.chPages(), function(page) {
                      return this.filterByThisPage(page.ID());
                  });
                  debugger;
return filtered;
}).bind(this);//, { deferEvaluation: true });

/* Finds out if the activeConnection exists for the page we want */
this.filterByThisPage = function(pageID){
alert('filterByThisPage');
ko.utils.arrayForEach(getPageConnections(), function(id) {
  if(id === pageID) return true;
});
return false;
}.bind(this);

/* Receive a page ID and get its connections array */
this.getPageConnections = function(){
alert('getPageConnections');
var getConnections = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.chPages(), function(page){
                      return this.activeConnection() === page.ID();
                     });

return getConnections.connections();
}
```

Somewhere along the road I've placed many alerts as you can see. The alert in the computed function only fires once and I think its due to the return null.

An important thing to notice is that supposively I want this to fire as we change the value of this.activeConnection() which is an observable variable that holds the ID of the page we clicked on (to see the children).

Any ideas on fixing the code as well as in making it more clean is very appreciated as I believe I am over complicating this.

EDIT:

I also tried deferEvaluation: true and in that case I always get a undefined error on my foreach data-binding.

EDIT 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/g1q99jr8/6/

This briefly explains my situation. There might be a few mistakes on the HTML part.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to do. What is `this.chPages`, what is `page`? Do you want to show all the `connections` of all the `pages`, or do you want to show the `connections` of a specific page? In the last case, you could put your currently active page in an observable, set the scope of your connection list parent element to that observable (e.g. `with: currentPage`) and then do a `foreach` on the `connections` property (e.g. `foreach: connections`).

Comment: Hello CornéM thanks for answering. chPages() are all the pages, its the observable array of var dummyPages. What I want to show is all the connections (childs) of a single page (so a single record in chPages()). The reason why I do things that way is because if you take notice of each page you'll see that connections is a bunch of IDs so I need to go through all the chPages() to get the information (alias and body). Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: well it would be better if you can fork this sample fiddle and explain your case http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22317/ . cheers

Comment: thanks for answering super cool. I will do it once I get the change and edit my post with it.

Comment: editted super cool :) http://jsfiddle.net/g1q99jr8/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Fiddle you provided, I've changed your code to achieve what I think you want to achieve. For array searching, I've used jQuery.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Write a number, please" id="number" />
<button type="submit" data-bind="click: changeActiveConnection">
    Click me!
</button>
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach:foreachConnectionAliases">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:alias" />
    <br />
</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    var page = function (ID, alias, body, connections) {
        this.ID = ko.observable(ID);
        this.alias = ko.observable(alias);
        this.body = ko.observable(body);
        this.connections = ko.observableArray(connections);
    };

    var dummyPages = [
        new page(1, 'Alias #1', 'Body #1', [5]),
        new page(2, 'Alias #2', 'Body #2', []),
        new page(3, 'Alias #3', 'Body #3', [2, 3]),
        new page(4, 'Alias #4', 'Body #4', [5]),
        new page(5, 'Alias #5', 'Body #5', [6]),
        new page(6, 'Alias #6', 'Body #6', [7]),
        new page(7, 'Alias #7', 'Body #7', [1, 4])];

    self.chPages = ko.observableArray(dummyPages);
    self.activePage = ko.observable();

    self.changeActiveConnection = function() {
        var number = +$('#number').val();

        // Find the selected page
        var match = $.grep(self.chPages(), function (e, i) {
           return e.ID() == number;
        });

        if (match.length < 1) // No element found
            return;

        self.activePage(match[0]);
    };

    /* Return the pages that are connected to the clicked one */
    self.foreachConnectionAliases = ko.computed(function() {
        var _page = self.activePage();

        if (_page == null || _page.connections().length < 1)
            return [];

        var aliases = [];

        // Loop through the connections of the current page
        _page.connections().forEach(function (e, i) {
            // Find the page again
            var connection = $.grep(self.chPages(), function (el, ix) {
                return el.ID() == e;          
            })[0];

            aliases.push(connection);
        });

        return aliases;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

And a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1q99jr8/8/).

Comment: I'm speechless.  Thanks! I was avoiding having a second array because I wanted everything to be connected. So if I change the connections on a page I want it to be automatically updated. I don't think I can achieve that easily though.

Answer (score 1):

well you are trying to filter out based on connection ID which is entered in textbox based on click function .

First point to note here is there is no need to use a `computed` here click function might me more than enough and can be done in very simple way

**View Model :**

```
    var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var page = function (ID, alias, body, connections) {
        this.ID = ko.observable(ID);
        this.alias = ko.observable(alias);
        this.body = ko.observable(body);
        this.connections = ko.observableArray(connections);
    };

    var dummyPages = [
    new page(1, 'Alias #1', 'Body #1', [5]),
    new page(2, 'Alias #2', 'Body #2', []),
    new page(3, 'Alias #3', 'Body #3', [2, 3]),
    new page(4, 'Alias #4', 'Body #4', [5]),
    new page(5, 'Alias #5', 'Body #5', [6]),
    new page(6, 'Alias #6', 'Body #6', [7]),
    new page(7, 'Alias #7', 'Body #7', [1, 4])];

    self.chPages = ko.observableArray(dummyPages);
    self.activeConnection = ko.observable();
    self.foreachConnectionAliases = ko.observableArray();

    /* Return the pages that are connected to the clicked one */

    self.changeActiveConnection = function () {
        self.foreachConnectionAliases([]);
        var conValue = self.activeConnection();

        if (typeof self.chPages === "undefined") return null;

        var filter = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.chPages(), function (page) {
            if (page.ID() == conValue) return true;
            else return false;
        });

        if(! filter) return true; 

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(filter.connections(), function (id) {
           ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.chPages(), function (page) {
                if (page.ID() == id) {
                    self.foreachConnectionAliases.push(page);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    }

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7lhd6ktw/1/)**

Any issue just in case let us know

Comment: Hey super cool thanks a lot for answering as well! I haven't had a chance to look at the whole code but something might be off as I press to get aliases of "1" and it returns me something different than expected. Same question I did to cormé is: Is it possible to automatically update the connections of a page? For example, as I interact with one of the pages returned by the array ( deleting one of them for example ) it would automatically reflect on the parent? ie: page 1 has connection with page 2 and 3. I delete page 2 and page 1 updates so it only has connection with page 3.

Comment: uff i misunderstood you requirement now corrected my code accordingly .just a small change thats all . attached working fiddle check it . cheers

Comment: `Is it possible to automatically update the connections of a page` . yes it will automatically updates as it is observableArray . when you remove something i hope you will remove from observableArray if thats the case everything is in order i assure you . cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your code works now! What was wrong? I will get back to you once I apply it to my project so I can see everything working. It will take me some time to analyze everything and do the remove functionality etc :) I will update you when I am ready!

Comment: actually i thought you are looking for something different like i tought you are entering connection number in your textbox then it should get alias names of all connections having a connection number entered , like say you entered 5 so i need to show alias1 and alias4 as both having a connection no 5 . anyways my bad .

Comment: Well I guess I explained it incorrectly, happens often so I wouldn't be surprised. Thanks :) One question though: Why do you do this: var conValue = self.activeConnection(); is it just to be more efficient in code writing? using conValue instead of always havign to write the self.activeConnection() ?

Comment: Hey super cool. I modified very little of your fiddle to my liking. http://jsfiddle.net/7fvzthtg/2/ Is there a reason why you chose in the end to use Filter over Foreach? That is the only question I have.

Comment: easy to maintain throughout and readable  . well it should be `foreach` my bad `filter` will do your work but make it foreach . mark the better ko answer . cheers